# How to mark <option> as selected in template with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some code which inserts data into a template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="yes-or-no-tpl">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="y" <%= "y" == value ? "selected" : "" }}>Yes</option>
    <option value="n" <%= "n" == value ? "selected" : "" }}>No</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

So far I have only found questions regarding how to react to a user selecting an option. I want to mark the option as selected before the user sees the field.

This code works, but I figured there must be a more elegant solution. Does Backbone have something built in to do this?

I checked out [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms), but I did not find any way to specify a pre-selected option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do it programmatically with jQuery after rendering the template. There's not much saving here for a yes-or-no template, but if you had 50 options in the select, it would reduce the verbosity a lot.

```js
var value = 'n'
  , tmpFn = _.template($('#yes-or-no-tpl').html())
  , $el = $('#result');
  
$el.html(tmpFn());
$el.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

// view.$el.html(tmpFn());
// view.$('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="yes-or-no-tpl">
  <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="y">Yes</option>
    <option value="n">No</option>
  </select>
</script>
<div id="result"/>
```

And in relation to *built in* options, Backbone doesn't include any data binding. You could look into an add-on library like [Epoxy.js](http://epoxyjs.org/tutorials.html#simple-bindings), but watch out for poorly maintained tools, might be more hassle in the long run.

Comment: I suspected jQuery might be the way to go. The example I gave it indeed simple. Most of the templates with this issue have over 10 options, some over 100. Thank you for the example.